# Codeigniter: Get Instance

Tags: codeigniter

What is the purpose of "Get Instance" in Codeigniter?
How would you explain this to a total beginner?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ok, so everything in CodeIgniter runs through the super-magic `$this` variable. This only works for classes, as `$this` basically defines the current class.

Your controller is a class, so $this is there, allowing you to do `$this->load->model('whatever');`

In models, you are also using a class. It is slightly different here, as `$this` only contains useful stuff as you are extending from Model. Still, `$this` is still valid.

When you are using a helper or a library, you need to find that "instance" or `$this` equivalent.

```
$ci =& get_instance();
```

…makes `$ci` contain the exact same stuff/code/usefulness as `$this`, even though you are not in a class, or not in a class that inherits it.

That's an explanation for total beginners after 2 pints, so it's either wrong or about right. ;-)

Comment: 2 pints, eh? Then what is the usefullness of a library/helper?  Why not just use models?

Comment: Of course seeing as everything is a PHP class you CAN put whatever you like wherever you like. Generally speaking in CodeIgniter it is broken down as "database interaction/business logic" = models, simple functions go in helpers and general classes are libraries.

Comment: @PhilSturgeon great explanation :)

Comment: Would expect anything less than 2 pints from Phil :-D

Answer (score 11):

It's an implementation of the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Essentially, there is only one instance of the class in question, which is designed to be accessible globally. The `get_instance` method is static and so provides a way of accessing the instance from anywhere in your code.

Comment: Not noobish enough.  I'm a SUPER NOOB! :)

Comment: @Kevin: In that case I recommend you start reading about object-oriented programming (OOP) before delving into a framework that relies upon it!