# Codeigniter superobject on libraries or helpers, use get_instance() or send $this?

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to understand if there's any performance diference when sending codeigniter superobject as a parameters instead of using  and assigning get_instante() to a var ?

For example,

HELPERS:

```
function callMe($CI)
{
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
callMe($this);
```

Instead of

HELPERS:

```
function callMe()
{
 $CI =& get_instance();
}
```

When I were typing this question I found [get_instance() in Codeigniter: Why assign it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195544/get-instance-in-codeigniter-why-assign-it-to-a-variable) wish was very usefull, but I think this is a more specific question.

Comment: Why would you rather want to ALWAYS have to pass in another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a ***slight*** performance improvement, but there's no way it is significant enough to warrant using this ugly syntax requiring you pass another param every time you call a helper method.