# CI Instances function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was looking around on here for a post that can help me to learn what is needed to globalize variables and instances of CI. I found this great post.

[get_instance() in Codeigniter: Why assign it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195544/get-instance-in-codeigniter-why-assign-it-to-a-variable)

The issue with this is that when I attempted it in my own application I received the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function CI() in .../application/core/MY_Controller.php on line 6
```

I'm not sure why this is. Can someone elaborate on it?

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $module;    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        CI()->module = $this->module = $this->router->fetch_module();
    }

    function CI()
    {
        static $CI;
        isset($CI) || $CI = CI_Controller::get_instance();

        return $CI;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the function inside your class, so you need to refer to it as an instance method

```
$this->CI()->module = $this->module = $this->router->fetch_module();
```