# Add url -segment of the input name on the form action

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am still learning CodeIgniter , how as add `uri->segement` from value input?

```
<form action="getdata" method="GET">
    <input name="id" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="month" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Example

```
name("id") = 001
name("month") = Feb
```

Result

```
<form action="getdata/001/feb" method="GET">
    <input name="id" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="month" type="text" value=""/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to add some parameters with form action url ?

Comment: Use JQuery to achieve that.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html - this link may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values from URL by using [`CI URI Class`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=uri%20segment)

**Example:**

```
<form action="getdata/001/feb" method="GET">
    <input name="id" type="text" value="<?=$this->uri->segment(2)?>"/>
    <input name="month" type="text" value="<?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Here:**

`$this->uri->segment(2)` will return ID (001) and 
`$this->uri->segment(3)` will return Name (Feb)

Comment: @channasmcs: yes it will work, no need to change instances.

Comment: thanks  all for answer, yes this work if using the method " GET " but the result /getData?id=001&month=02 , what if the results /getData/001/02

Comment: @Duwiirwanto: for this, u need to use htaccess, and than use uri segment

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $ci =& get_instance(); ?>
<form action="getdata/001/feb" method="GET">
 <input name="id" type="text" value="<?=$ci->uri->segment(2)?>"/>
 <input name="month" type="text" value="<?=$ci->uri->segment(3)?>"/>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

[get_instance() in Codeigniter: Why assign it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195544/get-instance-in-codeigniter-why-assign-it-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like

```
if (id == 001 && month == Feb) {
 do something;
} else {
do whatever?;
}
```