# Is there different between calling $CI and using `this` in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get_instance() in Codeigniter: Why assign it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195544/get-instance-in-codeigniter-why-assign-it-to-a-variable)

I have a controller, and it have lots of functions, I would like to separate them into different cmd object. But in controller, I can do the `$this` magic, for example, I can call something like this:

`$this->form_validation->run('myAction');`

But when I move this code to an object, which is not a controller, so, I called the function like this:

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->form_validation->run('myAction');
```

I realize that they can run, and the result is exactly what I want. But, my question is, is these two operation or codes have any different? What is the `get_instance()` black magic inside? Did the controller's `$this` refer to the same `get_instance()`? Thanks.

Comment: based on the answer given here, i daresay they are the same


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819435/codeigniter-get-instance

Comment: from the name itself get_instance() an instance of the class that has been initialized. $this refers to the methods loaded when extending the core controller CI_Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `$ci = &get_instance()`, you're directly using the codeigniter native libraries, you're not making a copy of it. The "`$this`" command can be used only in inside the controllers, so assign the CI object to a variable is the only way you've got to go inside the Ci core libraries outside the controller. Note that the "`$this`" command inside a model refer to the model object itself.