# Loading model function inside a webservice function

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, soap, model

I'm working in a codeigniter based project with integrated SOAP webservices, and I fail to load a model function inside a registered webservice function.

I have this 2 functions in SOAP webservice: hello and addcontact.

```
function hello($name) {
            return 'Hello, ' . $name;
    }
```

and

```
function addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad) {            
        $resultado=$this->modelo_turismo->addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad);

        if($resultado){
            return "Bienvenido $nombre $apellido. Tu eres de $ciudad.";
        }else{
            return "No se pudo agregar contacto.";
        }            
    }
```

Function hello is simple and its working fine when service is consumed by client, unlike function addcontact that is showing this message when trying to be consumed:

```
Response not of type text/xml: text/html
```

As you can see, I'm loading a function within model that inserts a contact to database, but im not even returning any database data to echo or print.

As well I've tried some other things trying to load the model, I cant get rid of that message, so I tried this (I know its weird to use a function to insert like this in CodeIgniter but im trying to learn why that message come):

```
function addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad) {
        $conexion = new mysql ("localhost","root","","turismo");
        if ($conexion->connect_errno){
            return "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conexion->connect_error;
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, apellido, ciudad) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$ciudad')";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
        if($resultado){
            return "Bienvenido $nombre $apellido. Tu eres de $ciudad.";
        }else{
            return "No se pudo agregar contacto.";
        }

    }
```

with that function I get this error again:

> Response not of type text/xml: text/html

But if I change the in the connection line 'mysql' to 'mysqli' like this:

```
$conexion = new mysqli ("localhost","root","","turismo");
```

I get the expected result when loading client:

> Bienvenido John Travolta. Tu eres de California.

I then suspected that the error I was getting loading the model was because in my database config file I had this line:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

so I tried to change the driver to 'mysqli' and no good results. I keep getting the same error:

> Response not of type text/xml: text/html

BTW, this is the way im registering 'addcontact' function:

```
$this->nusoap_server->register('addcontact',                // method name
        array('nombre' => 'xsd:string',
            'apellido' => 'xsd:string',
            'ciudad' => 'xsd:string'),        // input parameters
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),      // output parameters
        'urn:Turismo_WSDL',                      // namespace
        'urn:Turismo_WSDL#addcontact',                // soapaction
        'rpc',                                // style
        'encoded',                            // use
        'Agregar reservacion'            // documentation
    );
```

and this is the client function, that consumes the function above:

```
function addcontact() {

    $wsdl = site_url('Webservice/wsdl');
    $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
    $client-> soap_defencoding='UTF-8'; 
    $client->decode_utf8 = true;

    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';

    }

    $result = $client->call('addcontact', array('nombre' => 'John', 'apellido'=>'Travolta', 'ciudad'=>'California'));

    // Check for a fault
    if ($client->fault) {
        echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Check for errors
        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err) {
            // Display the error
            echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
        } else {
            // Display the result
            echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
            print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, what I'm doing wrong? I can do the work with a manual connection like described above, but I want to work with the model as in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

We can call the codeigniter models using instance variable

`$ci =& get_instance();`

```
Class soap
{
    private $ci;

    // set the CI classes to  $CI
    function __constuct(){
       $this->ci = & get_instance ();
    }

    function callone(){
      $resultado=$this->ci->modelo_turismo->addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad);
    }


}
```

`ci->` will provide the models from CI

Please refer this for more about codeigniter Instance variables
[Codeigniter: Get Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819435/codeigniter-get-instance)

Comment: I configured my nusoap_server in a CI controller, 'class Webservice extends CI_Controller{' and I have code like this in __construct() function: '$this->nusoap_server = new nusoap_server();', I really dont know why im getting that message even with get_instance();